# SQLite: Need Date >= (x) number of days from today

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsdate

Trying to select a date (x) days from today's date, where the date would be start of day (e.g. 12:00am that day).

For example, a query with date 5 days earlier..

```
@"select pkey, dateofmod from data WHERE dateofmod >= date('now', '? days')" ,  [NSNumber numberWithInt:-5];
```

doesn't seem to work. (using FMDB).

Comment: You might find the details on this question/answer useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711504/how-get-datetime-column-in-sqlite-objecite-c/1711591#1711591

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
sqlite> SELECT date( julianday(date('now')));
2009-08-19
sqlite> SELECT date( julianday(date('now'))+2);
2009-08-21
```

`julianday` does "round" to midnight:

```
sqlite> SELECT datetime( julianday(date('now')));
2009-08-19 00:00:00
sqlite> SELECT datetime( julianday(date('now'))+2);
2009-08-21 00:00:00
```

Usually with SQLite you want to use `julianday` if you are adding a number of days to a date.

[SQLite Date and Time Functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can always do select Top X.

```
@"select TOP X from data WHERE dateofmod >= date('now', '? days')" ,  [NSNumber numberWithInt:-5];
```