# Inserted date of record in sqlite3 database?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I inserted a record in an sqlite3 database. I want to know the date on which that table inserted in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlite3 does not store change dates automatically, so if you want to get them later you should insert the date to database yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite function julianday('now') will return a floating point value that represents the current date and time. This can be used in an insert.

You may also want to check out this question and its answer(s).
[How get a datetime column in SQLite with Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711504/how-get-datetime-column-in-sqlite-objecite-c/1711591#1711591)