# is there any easy way to get Date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm new to iPhone development. I want to set default date to NSDate Object as string. I don't see any easy way or method...

I think there might be a method in NSCalender? If there's such a method, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Added time to format string.

You will need to look at the [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes. Here's a simple example of how to use them:

```
NSString* defaultDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2011-01-22 15:30:00"];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* defaultDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:defaultDateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```

and if you wanted to get the string from a date you can just use:

```
NSString* defaultDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:defaultDate];
```

Comment: yup buddy i forgot sudenly i get answer from my own code.......BUT thank you very much for give me time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you are asking, but to create an instance of an NSDate object with the current date, one calls:
NSDate * myDate = [NSDate date];

If you are saying that you have a c-string or NSString that needs to be parsed to initialize an NSDate object, that's another question.

I have some code posted here:
[How get a datetime column in SQLite with Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711504/how-get-datetime-column-in-sqlite-objecite-c/1711591#1711591)

that shows how to create NSDates from NSStrings using NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an NSDate from a string, you need to use an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do it. It's important to note that the formatter will use the current locale's time zone when constructing the date, unless you put a time-zone in as part of the format. For more information about constructing time zones, see [NSTimeZone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For example, to create a date using the ubiquitous format '2011-01-16 00:00' in UTC, you would do:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
// Only certain abbreviations are okay, like UTC. See docs for more info
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

NSDate* midnight_26_jan_2011_utc = [formatter dateFromString:@"2011-01-26 00:00"];

// this will display in your system locale
// (for me, it shows 2011-01-25 19:00 +0500 because I'm America/New_York time)
NSLog(@"date: %@", midnight_26_jan_2011_utc);
[formatter release];
```

Comment: hi jason thank you for answer but i have problem in taking 24hr time..  if i take 13:00 than it not work properly in my Counter so help me

Comment: @Ankit you can use 12 hour time too, or no time at all. If you don't care about the time part, don't put the HH:mm in there; if you want 12-hour time you can use hh:mm instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; //here,you can set the date format as you need

NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init]autorelease];
NSString *theDate = [DateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Now, you can use the string the date. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-01-26"];
```

Comment: Four spaces indentation is all you need for a code block. Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: 'mm' is the specifier for minutes, not months. So your example /looks/ like it works because January is the default month, but this actually creates a date of 26 Jan 2011 at 00:01 hours local time. If your date was say '2011-10-01', the created date would be 1 /Jan/ 2011 at 00:10 local O_O Be careful!

Comment: ok it`s fine but it not take 24 hR time for that what can i do?