# Creating a DateType field on sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

i want to create a table on sqlite with one field as DateTime (YYYY-MM-DD) , how i can create it?

i'm trying with:

```
create table test (_date datetime);
```

but i'm not sure if the datatype is correct 'cause i can do this:

```
create table test (_date nyanType);
```

and no error occours

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711504/how-get-datetime-column-in-sqlite-objecite-c/1711591#1711591

Answer (score 6):

SQLite is rather unique in that its columns are not statically typed. You can technically store a string in a column that was created as an integer column.

If you check out the [SQlite Documentation](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for types, you'll see that SQLite dosn't have a date type, but it exposes date and time functions that are suitable for manipulating dates that are stored as TEXT, REAL or INTEGER. You should use those instead.