# read date("DateTime" Type) in to sqlite3 database in iPhone

Tags: datetime, sqlite

Which column type is used for read date in to sqlite database in iphone

Answer (score 0):

SQLite 3 does not have a DateTime data type. However, you can easily store the date in a TEXT, REAL or Integer.

See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: i have insert date into database... 

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSString *dateString=[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
 sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [dateString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT); 

and read.......

 1....char *date_char = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3); 
 2....double date = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3); 

Output is...

 1....null
 2....2012(display only year)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711504/how-get-a-datetime-column-in-sqlite-with-objective-c